# Why graphQl returns "Unknown argument 'first' on field..." error when trying to slice on query?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to fetch first five items of a set. My query is following:

```
query sequence($id: String) {
  sequence(id: $id) {
    items(first:1) {
            content
    }
  }
}
```

How ever, I get response

> "Unknown argument \"first\" on field \"items\" of type \"Sequence\"."

As far as I understood from [the docs](http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/) this is how I am supposed to make query if I want to get a limited amount of items back.

Do I need to define the argument somewhere in the schema? How do I limit the amount of returned items properly?

Answer (score 7):

All field arguments need to be defined in the schema, the default behaviour is for a field to accept no arguments.

You can define a `first` argument in your `items` field in your schema using syntax like this:

```
  type Sequence {
    items(first: Int): [Item]
  }
```

(See: [Example No. 120](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#example-1891c) in the spec.)